# How to send email Symfony 2 + AWS SES + Swiftmailer?

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have moved an application to amazon builded in symfony2 and using swiftmailer for sending emails, I am not able to send emails from the application.

So searching around the solution for sending emails. Please let me know if any solutions for sending email SES or configuring SMTP for symfony2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got mine to work with the following details:

```
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
auth_mode:  login
encryption: tls
port:  587
logging:  "%kernel.debug%"
```

And lastly, make sure the send FROM email address is verified.

Comment: Be aware that this configuration WILL NOT work if you specify port 465! (Because it uses different authentication mechanism). 587 Seems to work just fine! .... Just lost 2 hours figuring out that...

Answer (score 1):

I never played with AWS SES but you can use [mailjet](https://mailjet.com/) to send email. You just need to configure Swiftmailer Transport to use their SMTP and you're done.

They also ensure that your email are well sending (ie: not in spam) by providing several technique. You will have to setup some of them.

They do not provide example for Swiftmailer, but here a good one for Zend (you will see how easy it is):

```php
$config = array(
  'ssl'      => 'ssl',
  'port'     => 465,
  'auth'     => 'login',
  'username' => 'your_Mailjet_API_Key',
  'password' => 'your_Mailjet_Secret_Key');

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('in-v3.mailjet.com', $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();

$mail->setFrom('your_sender@address.com', 'You');
$mail->addTo('recipient@example.com', 'Anybody');
$mail->setSubject('My first email by Mailjet');
$mail->setBodyText('Hello from Mailjet & Zend Framework !');

$mail->send($transport);
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention to Mailjet. Since 2014, Mailjet has released a new major version of its platform. The V1 is still working but it's better to start with the V3. The SMTP address is now in-v3.mailjet.com

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SES has an excellent Php API from the official AWS Php SDK:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-ses.html

As you can see, SES is not used as a SMTP gateway (like Mailjet does) but as a HTTP API (via Guzzle, a Php library for HTTP queries). It's always an important decision to rely or not on Amazon services such as S3/SeS/SNS etc... maybe you don't want to depend on no Amazon technology?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use AWS SES Monitor Bundle to manage the sending of emails through SwiftMailer with Symfony.

The problem is that when you start with AWS SES you are in the sandbox and to go live you need to file an issue to Amazon to ask to put you out of the sendbox.

The requirement is that you can manage bounces and complaints.
To get notifications about those, you need to connect to Simple Notification Service (the other option is to get notifications via e-mail).

To automate all this stuff, you can use [AWS SES Monitor Bundle](http://github.com/Aerendir/aws-ses-monitor-bundle) that do all of this for you.
It also registers a plugin for SwiftMailer that can intercept messages and avoids the sending of messages to address to which you should not send e-mails.